# What scaling system to use in Box2d?

Tags: box2d, sfml

I'm worried about this *Caution* box from the [Box2d manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.pdf):

> Box2D is tuned for MKS units. Keep the size of moving objects roughly between 0.1 and 10 meters. You'll need to use some scaling system when you render your environment and actors. The Box2D testbed does this by using an OpenGL viewport transform. DO NOT USE PIXELS.

I don't want to use OpenGL since I know nothing about it. I'm using SFML to render my game.

Comment: Are you trying to scale elements based on the screen size?

Comment: i guess... im pretty newbie about that. Please help. Give advice.

Comment: I'm trying to help, but if you don't know what the issue is, then I can't provide a solution. I'm not familiar with Box2D, but if its using OpenGL to position elements, and you don't want to use that, then I'd advice to use another tool that is using pixels instead.

Comment: Box2d has a framework called "TesBed" that uses openGl viewport transform as scaling system. But i can use any other system in my app im sure of it.

Comment: What are you trying to do? What do you need simulated? Can your objects fit in the [0.1..10.0] range?

Comment: @Vaillancourt, want to write a game using Box2d for creating physics(maps, objects etc).

Comment: Ok, then where is the issue? It does not appear like you need any form of scaling.

Comment: @Vaillancourt, when i render box2d objects i need to use some scaling system to see my objects on screen.

Comment: How do you render your objects?

Comment: @Vaillancourt,using SFML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This caution box is telling you to not base your physics simulation on pixels. The pixels your game will be able to show will not be the same across all device, and is not a reliable measure to have your game consistent.

What it suggests is that you use "real world" sized objects in your *simulation*, and use your rendering engine to *display* the simulation. You really want to separate the two concerns and think in "real world" objects rather than in "pixels" (these become smaller each year that goes by).

In their examples, they use the concept of OpenGL's *viewport*, which is used to control what is rendered on the window.

In your case, might want to look into [SFML's View](https://www.sfml-dev.org/tutorials/2.5/graphics-view.php). I have not worked with SFML a lot, but this is basically a wrapper of OpenGL's *viewport* concept.

So for example, you'll simulate your car with real dimensions (say 1.8m x 4.6m), you'll stick a sprite which has that scale to it, but you'll ask SFML to render a parking lot of 200 x 200 units (where units are 'meters' in your game). It'll scale the *view* appropriately so that it fits in your render window.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that.What is that thing other people use then? They just multiply meters * pixels. I can do the same?

Comment: You could do that if you used another kind of rendering system. If you use SFML, don't do that, SFML has the feature coded for you in the view I describe above.

Comment: So okay. After i set up the viewport i can just use meters in box2 code and pixels in sfml code simple as that?

Comment: Yeah, I guess you can do that. The core thing is, really, keep your simulation in MKS, and convert the positions in pixels once you're at the rendering stage.

Comment: Wait so i have to do it manually when at rendering stage? Like pos * SCALEFACTOR?

Comment: If you use SFML's view to match your world, you'll only need to scale your sprites to fit your objects at creation time (`sprite.setScale(sf::Vector2f(0.5f, 2.f));`). Then everything will be in "real world" coordinates.

Comment: wow that sounds great. But how exactly do i set it to view my world?

Comment: You'll have to read the doc. The page I linked is pretty good at explaining it. You scale your srpites based on your real-world simulated bodies, each frame you process the box2d simulation, then you update the position of your sprites with the position of your bodies, then you just draw your sprites, making sure that your window has been set with a view. You modify the parameters of the view as you see fit.

Comment: Well i still cant grasp it. Please provide some visual example. I define my body positions at (10,10) and it doesnt change anything unless i multiply those values  when rendering.

Comment: Please [join the chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19/game-development).